# K-Means time series clustering with multiple time series for each data point

Tags: python, time-series, clustering, k-means

I have been trying to cluster my data through K-Means. However, for each datapoint that I have, there is 4 different time series (In, Out for Weekend/Wekeday). I have been looking to do multivariate clustering using `tslearn.clustering` `TimeSeriesKMeans` but am unsure how to cluster with multiple time series.

I did not simply concat all the data together as I assume that the clustering would not separate between each datapoint (using dtw as a metric).

Would appreciate any help given.